# Are there glitches with trying to use SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 to manage MSSQL 2005 DB instances?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm currently using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio ver. 9.00.4035.00 to manage my SQL Server 2005 (90) compatible databases.

Will I encounter problems should I attempt to upgrade the Management Studio software to SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 to manage MSSQL 2005 DB instances? I will not be upgrading the version of the database instance.

Answer (score 0):

My personal expreience says that you wont have any migration issues if you have sql server 2005 db instances. The attach and detach of DB is same in 2008 version. Only thing is, once you use a 2005 instance DB and attach it to 2008 version, it cannot be used with 2005 version again. Apart from that, from functionality point of view, there are no issues, you can continue to use the 2005 version DB on 2008 as normal.

link for moving the DB from 2005 to 2008 -

http://www.packtpub.com/article/moving-a-database-from-sql-server-2005-to-sql-server-2008-in-three-steps

EDIT: Incase you want to move back to 2005 version for same DB instance, I dont think it will be possible except for doing a data export import onto new 2005 DB instance.

Comment: He said he wouldn't be upgrading - just managing the old version servers from the new GUI.

Comment: If this is just to manage, then you wont be able to use both versions of sql on same DB instance.